# Failing verify msi package with MsiVerifyPackage()

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-installer

I am trying to identify msi file type, and I found MsiVerifyPackage() function which I am using like this:

```
LPCWSTR path = L"/My/File/Path";
UINT msiResult = 0;

msiResult = MsiVerifyPackageW(path);

if (ERROR_SUCCESS == msiResult)
{
    ...
}
```

But it is always giving me ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_OPEN_FAILED. I checked '.exe' and '.msi'. The msi that I was placing gives me an error to install some dependency. So I am stuck a little bit here. Ole and msi files have the same header, so this is not the case to check. Maybe I should use another function but I need a way to distinguish msi from ole file format. Please advice, thanks.

Comment: ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_OPEN_FAILED means this installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and is accessible, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.     If the suffix has not been tampered with, it is recommend to the method that file suffix check file type,

Comment: The package exist, but if I try to open it by clicking, it says that I need to run some script. So as I understand this is an online installer that I took from C:\Windows\Installer. So the package is correct.